# ASP .NEt MVC User profile based login user and redirect to designation url as per profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help with login based on profile. I created login action , but unable to direct user to specific urls based on their profile. Below if my code
Following Roles created

1. Admin
2. Auditor
3. Employee

1.) User Class

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
     }
```

2. Role Master Class

```
public class RoleMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string RollName { get; set; }
    }
```

3. UserRoleProvider Class

```
    public class UserRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            using (Db context = new Db())
            {
                var userRoles = (from user in context.Users
                                 join roleMapping in context.UserRolesMappings
                                 on user.Id equals roleMapping.Id
                                 join role in context.RoleMasters
                                 on roleMapping.RoleID equals role.RoleID
                                 where user.Username == username
                                 select role.RollName).ToArray();
                return userRoles;
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

4. UserRoleMapping Class

```
public class UserRolesMapping
    {
        [Key]
        public int URMID { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual User Users { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RoleID")]
        public virtual RoleMaster RoleMasters { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

5. Login form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
                <div class="card card-signin my-5">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">TickeTool</h5>
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <form class="form-signin">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-12",@placeholder="Username here.." } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password,new { @class = "form-control col-md-12",@placeholder="Password here.."  })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                
                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                            <hr class="my-4">

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

6. Controller to send login request

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(User model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (Db db = new Db())
                {

                    bool isValidUser = db.Users.Any(x => x.Username == model.Username && x.Password == model.Password);

                    if (isValidUser)
                    {
                        
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
                        return RedirectToAction("MyTickets", "Ticket");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        bool isUserValid = db.Users.Any(x => x.Username != model.Username && x.Password != model.Password);
                        if (isUserValid)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username / Password is Invalid");
                            return View(model);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260728/asp-net-mvc-login-and-redirect-based-on-role)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526536/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-2-login-redirect-based-on-user-role) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937186/redirect-users-according-to-their-identity-role-asp-mvc-4-and-5)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC Login and Redirect Based On Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260728/asp-net-mvc-login-and-redirect-based-on-role)

Comment: no success, tried the above options