# MVC Razor Login form ReturnUrl based on role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, authentication

I have the following login code

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", New With {.ReturnUrl = ViewData("ReturnUrl")}, FormMethod.Post, New With {.class = "form-horizontal", .role = "form"})
```

I want to change the ReturnUrl so a specific page based on the User.IsInRole, can this be done in razor?

Ended up removing the line as per below and adding the following

```
 Case SignInStatus.Success
            If User.IsInRole("Candidate") Then
                Return RedirectToLocal("/Candidate")
            Else
                Return RedirectToLocal("/Company")
            End If
```

Weird the above is only working for the Company?

Comment: Why not let it post and determine which view you go to based on logic found in your controller?

Comment: Sounds ideal but just not sure how to do this

Comment: @Stephen Let it post back normally and in your controller check the user role and send them to the appropriate view there.  return View("adminView")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
New With {.ReturnUrl = ViewData("ReturnUrl")},
```

part of your line and the system will look for a method named Login in your Account controller.

Comment: Implemented as above but only works with company...

Comment: Roles are not loaded at this point, most likely, so it's always hitting your Else.  see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273598/why-does-isinrole-always-return-false

Comment: Thanks...that was the issue. all sorted.